# Installing applet (Java Card) on J3A081

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I've just created a very simple applet. It's a "hello world" in Java card technology. I pasted a code below.

```
public class helloworld extends Applet {
    private byte[] echoBytes;
    private static final short LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES = 256;
    /**
     * Installs this applet.
     * 
     * @param bArray
     *            the array containing installation parameters
     * @param bOffset
     *            the starting offset in bArray
     * @param bLength
     *            the length in bytes of the parameter data in bArray
     */
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new helloworld();
    }

    /**
     * Only this class's install method should create the applet object.
     */
    protected helloworld() {
        echoBytes = new byte[LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES];
        register();
    }

    /**
     * Processes an incoming APDU.
     * 
     * @see APDU
     * @param apdu
     *            the incoming APDU
     */
    @Override
    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        //Insert your code here
        //
        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        if ((buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] ==  0) && (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) (0xA4))){
            return;
        }
        short bytesRead = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        short echoOffset = (short) 0;

        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, echoBytes, echoOffset, bytesRead);
        echoOffset += bytesRead;

        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)(echoOffset + 5));

        //echo header
        apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 5);
        //echo data
        apdu.sendBytesLong(echoBytes, (short) 0, echoOffset);
    }
}
```

After that I decided to install it on real card (J3A081) using Global Platform but it failed. 
First of all, I checked if there is any applet already installed on card with command:

```
java -jar gp.jar -l
```

The response is:

```
AID: A000000003000000 (|........|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected, CVM (PIN) management
```

When I decided to install applet using *.cap file I've got:

```
java -jar gp.jar -install krystian.cap

javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x1f
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:219)
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(ChannelImpl.java:90)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.transmit(GlobalPlatform.java:661)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:727)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:686)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:453)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x1f
        at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardTransmit(Native Method)
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:188)
        ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x1f
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:219)
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(ChannelImpl.java:90)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.transmit(GlobalPlatform.java:661)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:727)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:686)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:453)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x1f
        at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardTransmit(Native Method)
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:188)
        ... 5 more
```

Could you tell me what i'm doing wrong. This card is completly new, never used before. I'm using ACR122U NFC Card reader and card J3A081 by NXP.

**EDIT**

After a few hours of tries I managed to achive a few things. First of all, I updated a drivers for ACR122U smart card reader. Moreover I get familiar with GPShell and created a simple script:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID a000000003000000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f   
card_disconnect
release_context
```

Which outputs:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID a000000003000000
Command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
Response <-- 6F658408A000000003000000A5599F6501FF9F6E06479100783400734A06072A864                                                                   886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B0                                                                   40215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E01029000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4                                                                   f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864                                                                   886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012                                                                   A026E01029000
Command --> 805000000853DFBA4B056DAE8800
Wrapped command --> 805000000853DFBA4B056DAE8800
Response <-- 0000510101086197846701020018CC282BD831DB0145313B12DB3E169000
Command --> 84820100103294E6632BFE5E59879A2C9C03EE345E
Wrapped command --> 84820100103294E6632BFE5E59879A2C9C03EE345E
Response <-- 9000
card_disconnect
release_context
```

So i guess that everything works fine, but when I want to install applet using this:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID a000000003000000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
install -file helloworld.cap -nvDataLimit 2000 -instParam 00 -priv 2
card_disconnect
release_context
```

I got an exception:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID a000000003000000
Command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
Response <-- 6F658408A000000003000000A5599F6501FF9F6E06479100783400734A06072A864                                                                   886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B0                                                                   40215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E01029000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4                                                                   f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864                                                                   886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012                                                                   A026E01029000
Command --> 8050000008ADBD20501C2C87A400
Wrapped command --> 8050000008ADBD20501C2C87A400
Response <-- 0000510101086197846701020019DFABEED157EA9E2F7E75EAA739E89000
Command --> 848201001014781742A86F6C5026B0D999238ABEBA
Wrapped command --> 848201001014781742A86F6C5026B0D999238ABEBA
Response <-- 9000
install -file helloworld.cap -nvDataLimit 2000 -instParam 00 -priv 2
Command --> 80E602001E07D0D1D2D3D4D50108A000000003000000000AEF08C6020160C80207D0                                                                   0000
Wrapped command --> 84E602002607D0D1D2D3D4D50108A000000003000000000AEF08C6020160                                                                   C80207D000B9A71938B63B8CFB00
Response <-- 009000
Command --> 80E80000EFC4820157010011DECAFFED010204000107D0D1D2D3D4D50102001F0011                                                                   001F000C000B0026000C003B0019000F0000005D00020001000C01010004000B01000107A0000000                                                                   62010103000C0108D0D1D2D3D4D50101000C06000C00800300FF0007010000001707003B00011018                                                                   8C0000188B00017A02308F00023D8C00033B7A0521198B00042D198B00053B7B0006031A037B0006                                                                   928D00073B19037B0006928B00087A08001900020001000103000C48656C6C6F20576F726C642100                                                                   00000005002600090680030003800301010000000600000103800A0103800A060500000006801002                                                                   03800A0809000F000000
Wrapped command --> 84E80000F7C4820157010011DECAFFED010204000107D0D1D2D3D4D50102                                                                   001F0011001F000C000B0026000C003B0019000F0000005D00020001000C01010004000B01000107                                                                   A000000062010103000C0108D0D1D2D3D4D50101000C06000C00800300FF0007010000001707003B                                                                   000110188C0000188B00017A02308F00023D8C00033B7A0521198B00042D198B00053B7B0006031A                                                                   037B0006928D00073B19037B0006928B00087A08001900020001000103000C48656C6C6F20576F72                                                                   6C64210000000005002600090680030003800301010000000600000103800A0103800A0605000000                                                                   0680100203800A0809000F00000067CDD7B27E70D011
load() returns 0x0000001F (Urzdzenie doczone do komputera nie dziaa.
```

Could anyone got a similar error? Do you know what thoes it means?

**EDIT 2**
I finally managed to install applet on my card. I used modified GlobalPlatformPro, as vlp wrote, it's necessary to change load block to 16 bytes.

But I was only able to install hello world applet, during processing mine, GlobalPlatformPro returned exception:

```
java -jar gp_16byteLoadBlock.jar --install inzynierka.cap
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: LOAD failed SW: 6A80
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:728)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:686)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:453)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that standard Java AWT (e.g. `Applet`) is not included in the smart card API.  But I'm nit sure what else replaces them.

Comment: First of all, this Applet is imported from javacard.framework which is included into JCDK. It's something diffrent than in normal Java API. 
I tested this application on simulator and everything works fine. I'm wondering that on card I have Java Card 2.2.2 but I developed application  using Java Card 3.0.

Comment: Are you using a contactless reader? If so, do try a contact reader.

Comment: I don't posses contact reader. But could you explain me a reason why this exception is thrown?

Comment: I have seen this error when card stopped responding (due to badly formed APDU (probably not the case as _GlobalPlatformPro_ just works) or when the card left the reader field). The error code is probably [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_GEN_FAILURE). Does loading some other applet work (e.g. [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/gpshell/helloworld.cap))? Generally you should use the corresponding JavaCard SDK (i.e. probably the 2.2.1 one, not sure there ever was a 2.2.2. version released), but...

Comment: ...in case of any mismatch the card would probably give you `WRONG DATA` response early during the LOAD (just a note: AFAIK it is the `.exp` files that matter in the SDK while compiling for a specific JC version). The error you are getting originates from the PCSC layer (most probably the `winscard`). I would try to load a different applet. It is a pity you do not have a different card reader. Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded applet which you mentioned in the comment. But unfortunatelly it also doesn't work. There was the same exception as pasted above. What else could I do? Contact reader is an only option?

Comment: Trying another reader was just an idea (if you had one). Maybe someone else can help you. Good luck!

Comment: It _might_ be worth trying to transmit shorter load blocks. You can achieve this by replacing the `wrapper.getBlockSize()` with some smaller constant (`16`/`32`/`64`/`128`) at line [724](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/master/src/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java#L724) of [GlobalPlatform.java](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/master/src/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java) and recompiling `gp.jar`. But I am afraid this won't help.

Comment: I was trying to install the simplest applet possible - hello world :) I'm using J3A081 which is dual interface card, may it be a reason for that error? Maybe you can recommend me another card which I should try?

Comment: I suspect the reader (googled a bit and found [this](http://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1132) which is in line with my suggestion to try smaller blocksize during the load). Try the suggested modification to the GlobalPlatformPro, it is easy: Download the [sources](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/archive/v0.3.4.zip), modify `GlobalPlatform.java` (use `16` instead of `wrapper.getBlockSize()` in `loadCapFile()`) and rebuild using `ant`...

Comment: You can try [this version](http://www.filedropper.com/gp16byteloadblock) I compiled myself.

Comment: It is definitely not a problem of J3A081 - I use it all the time with no problems both contact and contactless interface (with Omnikey readers).

Comment: @vlp with this version which you posted I finally managed to install applet on the card :) Thank you a lot. But it still doesn't work with my applet. I will keep you informed about the progress.

Comment: @vojta I have another question to you. Do you develop you applets using Java Card 3.0.5 or older version? I'm wondering if this last exception with load problems may be caused because wrong version of Java Card SDK.

Comment: I use Java Card 2.2... Honestly, I have never heard of J3A081 that supports Java Card 3.

Comment: Okey, I newbie in Java card technology :) I will reconfigure eclipse to compile this applet with Java Card 2.2

Comment: Glad to hear that, so it is probably confirmed that it was a reader problem -- good to know that. You might want to increase the block size (it is up to you, 16 is extremely small)...Regarding JC SDK version -- use the corresponding one, it is the safest way. Good luck! PS: You might want to reconsider deleting the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656442/globalplatform-exception-during-installing-applet)

Comment: @vlp Yes, I've forgotten about this question. It's deleted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Transcript of discussion in comments)

It turned out, that the ACR122U NFC Card reader has problems with long APDUs (mentioned [here](http://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1132) as well).

One of possible solutions is to modify the [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/tree/v0.3.4) tool in the following way:

- get the sources [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/archive/v0.3.4.zip)
- locate the part of code which retrieves blocks of load file at [GlobalPlatform.java:724](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/v0.3.4/src/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java#L724)
- decrease the load block size by replacing the `wrapper.getBlockSize()` part with some smaller constant (`32` is confirmed to work and `64` is confirmed not to work with this reader)
- recompile GlobalPlatformPro

EDIT>

The latest GlobalPlatformPro code [adds](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/commit/15acce13d484a72f0535d16bb1aed63002144eb8) a `-bs` option, which allows you to set the block size without recompiling.

Comment: I've just tried to compile replace `wrapper.getBlockSize()` with  constant `32` and it works. When you change it to `64` it fails to install *.cap file.

Comment: @Krystian Great, I updated the answer. Theoretically the maximum for the default mode (which is MAC) is 40 (assuming the maximum allowed APDU data of 48 bytes as mentioned in the [Yubico forum post](http://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1132)).

Comment: @Krystian Apropos, have you managed to load your applet (compiled for JC 2.2)?

Comment: This is the time where I chime in, wishing that somebody would care to open a bug/feature request. Even though in this case it seems to come from a broken reader/driver and nothing (sensible) can be done on GP side, an option could be added so that folks would not have to recompile thing (if you check the code, it would be "nice" to check the card-reported maximum block size but I've never seen a card that would need it)

Comment: @MartinPaljak You are right. Actually, I was deciding to contact you, but then I let it go as it is almost sure a reader problem (can't check myself as I do not own the reader, but my bet is that it has something to do with the ISO 14443-4 framing). About the card-reported maximum block size -- do you mean the 0x9F65 tag in the FCI?

Comment: Latest source code allows you to use `-bs 32` (must not be a power of 2, by the way) instead of changing the utility source code.

Comment: Using gp -d -v -install MyApplet.cap -bs 64 helped to solve my problem. When deploying empty applet, I had no problem. Immediately after adding one private field of type short on applet class, problem appeared.