# Command not allowed - Conditions of use not satisfied when installing applet

Tags: eclipse, smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

I am trying to install a simple applet on a Java Card but I got the error:

> *load returns 0x80206985 Command not allowed - Conditions of use not satisfied when installing applet*

The code seems is working on Eclipse's simulator, but when I want to convert it and send the CAP file to the card I get the above error. I use GPShell for installing the applet. The installer script is listed below

```
mode_201
gemXpressoPro
enable_trace
enable_timer
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID A000000018434D00
open_sc -security 3 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -key 47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45
install -file sid.cap 
card_disconnect
release_context
```

The SDK for Java Card is version 2.2.2 and for converting I used Eclipse-JCDE0.2. I got the same kind of error when I try to install any other applet. I also tried to downgrade the Java Card SDK to version 2.1.1 but that didn't solved my problem. I attached below a screenshot with the problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your smart card is a Gemalto card? This error mean either your authentication key is not correct (Your card is not a Gemalto card, or the authentication key has been changed already) or your card is locked (By 10 wrong tries for authentication). Anyway, GPShell is an old tool, I suggest you to use [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases) instead.

Comment: Yes,I'm sure.Actualy I succeed in installing an helloworld.cap on the card.It seems that the way I generate the .cap seems to be wrong

Comment: Ah, maybe! I was wrong about the Status word. `0x69 82` is for wrong authentication. Yours is `0x6985`. Are you sure that the version of `CAP` file is supported by your card?

Comment: The next step is to change the Java Card SDK from 2.2.2 to 2.1.2.From the specification the card should support Java Card 2.2.2

Comment: @Drago It could also be that the generated code isn't Java Card compatible somehow. Writing to static byte arrays for instance could result in an error, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Another package/instance with the same AID might be installed on the card. You can check with the [get_status](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/#status-commands) command.

Comment: Are you installing as default selected and there is already a default selected applet on the card?

Comment: And is Javacard API and GLobal Platform version compatible to the hardware?

Comment: @vlp  is seems that GpShell was the problem.I managed to convert the applet to Java Card 2.2.1 and all the thing worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by downgrade from Java Card 2.2.2 to Java Card 2.2.1 . It seems that was a compatibility problem between Java Card SDK and GpShell version I used.

Answer (score 3):

The error that you received while uploading the applet code (LOAD command) indicates that the on-card verification process discovered something in your applet code base that it does not accept (e.g. use of a framework class that does not exist, use of a method that does not exist, an invalid instruction, etc.)

This also matches your experience that downgrading from Java Card SDK 2.2.2 to Java Card SDK 2.2.1 worked. Btw. GPShell does not care about the Java Card version, it's the card that generates that error.

Comment: My solution to this was mentioned:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618618/installing-applet-java-card-on-j3a081. 
Increased APDU buffer size.